# Convert list with duplicates into dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

i have a `List<Tuple<long,string>>`  like :

```
id value
1   hello
2   what
1   why
3   how
4   when
3   who
```

there could be multiple values for the same id, i want to convert the list into a dictionary of `long, List<string>` where id is the key and value is list of all corresponding value strings,

how can i do that? 
I tried using ToDictionary but it throws exceptions.
thanks for your help guys

Comment: Sounds like you need to `GroupBy()` something...

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you think you need a `long`?

Comment: `.ToLookup(x=>x.Item1,x=>x.Item2)` .....